# Overlay is clickable through an element in front of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using an overlay for a login which appears in front of everything when the user hit "sign-in". The overlay consists of an opaque wrapper which contains a solid inner-div where the login form is held.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="login_wrapper"> 
    <div class="login_info">
        <div class="login_form">
             // form 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.login_wrapper{
    position:absolute; 
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index:9998;
    display: none;
}
.login_info{
    font-family: "NimbusCondensed";
    position:absolute; 
    margin: auto;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 350px; 
    height:300px; 
    background: #cacaca; 
    border: solid #000000 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index:99999;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.login_form{
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    padding: 10 20 0 20;
    width: 220px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 13px black;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

I would like this overlay to be hidden when the user clicks anywhere outside of the login_info.

I have the following JQuery handling this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".login_wrapper").click(function(){ 
        $(".login_wrapper").fadeToggle(300);  
    });
});
```

But *login_wrapper* is hidden if the use clicks ANYWHERE on the overlay, including the form in the middle which prevent then form entering any info.

Somehow the click events are getting "through" *login_form* & *login_info* and the browser reacts like *login_wrapper* is clicked.

How can I resolve this so that jQuery code applies ONLY when the overlay is clicked outside the inner divs.

Thanks!

Comment: Try use event.stoppropogation() in jQuery in click event

Comment: Well, since your login form and login info are inside your login wrapper, it's logic to say that when you click on login form you also click on login wrapper, therefore the effect.

Comment: good point. I figured because the form is layered in front of the wrapper, the click event would not propagate "through it". no?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".login_wrapper").click(function(){ 
        $(".login_wrapper").fadeToggle(300);  
    });
    $(".login_info").click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

This will stop the click event from bubbling up to the `.login_wrapper`. For more information on `stopPropagation()` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to transform `.login_wrapper` in `#login_wrapper`, then add this:

```
$('#login_wrapper').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "login_wrapper")
    $('#login_wrapper').fadeToggle(300);
});
```

This will target only the element with the id `login_wrapper`.
Hope this helps